# Multiplyall() with the arguments object and object.Values()

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rum2.png)[enter image description here][2]The task is to create a function that will multiply all the parameters passed to the function. The number of those parameters varies and is unknown. One should use the arguments object and the static function Object.values()

[As you can see i tried something but it only multiplies the first two parameters. In addition I dont really understand why the console.log(arguments.lenght) is 5 when i clearly only have 4 parameters in the Multiplyall function. .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM04D.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rum2.png)

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `while`, use the `for` statement. Read about the difference here: [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) / [while statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). The corresponding function would then look something like this:

```
function multiplyAll_v1() {
    let res = 1;
    if ( arguments.length < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for( let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        res *= arguments[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

You can of course also use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax for the function. The corresponding function would then look something like this:

```
function multiplyAll_v2( ...args ) {
    let res = 1;
    if ( args.length < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for ( let arg of args ) {
        res *= arg;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Finally, here's a working example including both variants:

```js
function multiplyAll_v1() {
    let res = 1;
    if ( arguments.length < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for( let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        res *= arguments[i];
    }
    return res;
}

function multiplyAll_v2( ...args ) {
    let res = 1;
    if ( args.length < 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for ( let arg of args ) {
        res *= arg;
    }
    return res;
}

console.log( multiplyAll_v1( 2, 3, 6 ), multiplyAll_v2( 2, 3, 6 ) );

document.getElementById( 'v1' ).innerHTML = "Result v1: " + multiplyAll_v1( 2, 3, 6 );
document.getElementById( 'v2' ).innerHTML = "Result v2: " + multiplyAll_v2( 2, 3, 6 );
```

```html
INPUT: 2, 3, 6
<p id="v1"></p>
<p id="v2"></p>
```